# Get multiple radio button values from django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My model contains passages and each passage have some questions and each question have four answers.
I wrote a simple form to show the questions and showed the related answers with radio buttons, but I can't retrieve the answer for a specific question in Django View

### Django Template:

```
<h2>Choose the right answer from the choices for any question</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'exam:submit' passage.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in passage.question_set.all %}
    <h5>{{ forloop.counter }}-{{question.text }}</h5>
        {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="answer[{{ question }}]"                                 
            id="answer{{ answer.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}" />
            <label for="answer{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.text }}</label>                                                                
            <br/>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

### Django View:

```
def submit(request, passage_id):
    passage = get_object_or_404(models.Passage, pk=passage_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer_list = request.POST.getlist('answer')
    context = {
        'List': answer_list,
        'passage': passage,
        }
    return render(request, 'exam/submit.html', context)
```

I want to show the list of answers that choose for their question in a list (e.g. [1, 2, 4, 3, 1] are the answers chosen for question 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
but the browser just shows an empty list (e.g. []).